# Is there a restriction on using JSP tags inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Is there some restrictions on using JSP tags inside a javascript?

I have a script like this:

```
<script>
<%int ccCount = 0;%>
var stockData = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < <%=sNum%>; i++)                 
{
    stockData[i] = {Supplier: "<%=sName[ccCount]%>", CC: <%=cc[ccCount]%>};
    <%ccCount++;%>
}
<script>
```

Every line inside JSP tags worked, except the <%ccCount++;%>. My sName and cc array kept pointing to the first index (0), can anyone tell me what went wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _server-side_ code and _client-side_ code.

Comment: Oh I bet it worked - only **there is no loop** in compiled Servlet.

Comment: The 2 don't interact like you seem to be expecting. JSP will run completely first on the server (outputing `sNum`, `sName[0]`, and `cc[0]`, then incrementing `ccCount` once). Only after that will the JavaScript begin to run, as the page is loaded into the client/browser (iterating `i` to 1 less than the output of `sNum`, filling in `stockData`).

Comment: For what it's worth, it's been about [10 years since using JSP that way was considered a good idea.](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/Journal200603.jsp#a5)

Comment: I see, seems it's not a good idea to use them together in this case. Thank you so much for the explanations :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSP is executed on the server. It ten send the resulting Javascript to the browser, where this part is executed.

What JSP/Java sees:

```
int ccCount = 0;
=sName[ccCount];
=cc[ccCount]%>};
ccCount++;
```

The resulting JavaScript is ( assumed `cc[ccCount]` would be 42 and `sNum`  12345)

```
<script>
var stockData = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 12345; i++)                 
{
    stockData[i] = {Supplier: "some value", CC: 42};
    43
}
<script>
```

As the JSP is executed on the sevrer, it's not part of the for-loop which is only existing in the browser.